# Google maps api v3 drop markers animation with delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I know there's a question about this [Google Maps API v3 drop markers from XML with delay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8576515/google-maps-api-v3-drop-markers-from-xml-with-delay) and I followed it, but I had to made a mistake in my code, here it is:

```
function dropAnim(lat,lng,name) {

    console.log("---- " + lat + " - " + lng);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({

        position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng),
        map: map,
        title: name,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        icon: imageCar,

    });

}

var counter = 0;

$.get('http://server.com/methods.php?m=loadPins', function(data) {

dataName = data.name.split(";");
dataLat = data.lat.split(";");
dataLng = data.lng.split(";");

dataLength = dataName.length-1;

for(var i=0;i<dataLength;i++) {

   var lat = dataLat[i];
   var lng = dataLng[i];

   console.log(lat + " - " + lng);

   setTimeout(function() {
      dropAnim(lat,lng,dataName[i]);
   }, counter * 400);

   counter++;
} 

},"json");
```

The problem is that it loads 3 pins in the exact same place. dataLat and dataLng load 3x times different and I can see that in console, but when I see what comes out in console from insde the function, there are 3 same lat and lng (the last one).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this:

```
 setTimeout((function(i) {
     return function(){
        dropAnim(dataLat[i],dataLng[i],dataName[i]);
     };
 })(i), counter * 400);
```

Your problem was, when your timeout's callback is called, `i` variable already has `dataLength` value, as your loop is already finished by that time.

Comment: I knew there was gonna be a clever folk who solves this thing in a minute. You're the man, thanks a lot!