# Animation of google markers on map load with timeout

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I would like to create a timeout on each google marker's DROP animation, but I think the closure code for the marker and the array item are conflicting. I do not know too much about closures and am getting a bit stuck on the problem.

I can get them all falling at once.

[falling markers code jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dj7vH/)

but I would like to have a timeout after every marker of 100 ms.

This is what I thought would work

```
...

//Loop through nc array
for (var i = 0; i < nc.length; i++) {

   //Create 100 ms rule on marker creation
   setTimeout(function () {

     //Create marker
     var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
       position: nc[i],
       map: map,
       title: "tron" + i,
       animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
     });

    }, i * 100);

   //Creating the closure
   (function (i, marker) {

     //Add infowindow
     google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
         if (!infowindow) {
            infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
         }
         //Setting content of info window
         infowindow.setContent('<h2>Tron lives | ' + i + '</h2>');
             infowindow.open(map, marker);
         });
      })(i, marker);
    };

...
```

But that does not work. I figure that once the markers are created in the loop one would set the timeout on that creation process which would create the falling rain marker effect.

Comment: Try moving the marker creation to a separate function.  Take a look at this answer and see if it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8576515/google-maps-api-v3-drop-markers-from-xml-with-delay

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Had the same thought as @Bryan Weaver.  Took your fiddle and modified it a bit to create the markers in a function, and iteratively set the timeout.  Ended up with what follows, and it successfully does your "rain" effect.

```
    var addmarker = function(i) {
        //Create marker
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: nc[i],
                map: map,
                title: "tron" + i,
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            });

            //Creating the closure
            (function (i, marker) {   

                //Add infowindow
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                    if (!infowindow) {
                        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                    }
                    //Setting content of info window
                    infowindow.setContent('<h2>Tron lives | ' + i + '</h2>');

                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                });
            })(i, marker); 
        if(i++ < nc.length) {
            setTimeout(function() {addmarker(i)}, 100);
        }

    }
    addmarker(0);
```

Here's the full fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/LzJ8B/

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
var map;
var service;
var infowindow;
var mapcenter;
var markers = [];

  function setMapOnAll(map) {
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      markers[i].setMap(map);
    }
  }
  /*init map*/
  function initMap(){
     mapcenter= new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8617374,151.2021291);
     map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
     center: mapcenter,
     zoom: 10
   });

    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  };
  /*end init map*/

  function findPlaces(){
    service.nearbySearch({
      location: mapcenter,
      radius: 50000,
      type:['animal hospital'],
      keyword: ['pet animal emergency clinic hospital']
    }, nearbyCallback);
  }

  function nearbyCallback(results, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
      setMapOnAll(null); //clear markers

      for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      /*important part of the code*/
          (function(results,i){
            if(results)
            setTimeout(function(){createMarker(results[i])},123*i);
          })(results,i)
      }
    }
  };

  function createMarker(place) {
    var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: place.geometry.location,
        animation:google.maps.Animation.DROP,
      });
        markers.push(marker);
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.setContent('<div><h4 style="margin:0;padding:0">'+place.name+'</h4><p style="margin:0;padding:0;font-size:12px">'+place.vicinity+'</p></div>');
        infowindow.open(map, this);
      });
  };

//call findplaces document.ready event
$(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){findPlaces();});
   });
 });
```

**In your HTML**

```
<div id="map"  class="col12" style="width:100%;height:100%"></div>
<button>Load Places</button>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=--your-api-key--=places&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```