# Google Marker Drop Animation with Timeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to create a DROP animation for a large quantity of Google Markers.
I don't want 300 (or so) markers falling at once so I did some searching and found the 'setTimeout' feature.

I have been following the instructions from this question:

[Animation of google markers on map load with timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17890678/animation-of-google-markers-on-map-load-with-timeout)

I am following the same steps as in the post above but can't seem to get the code working in my example.

Here is what I thought would work...

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: 6,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(54.059170, -4.797820),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});


var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

var marker, i;

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    map: map,
    icon: EuroPCmarker,
  });


  (function (i, marker) {


  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });

  })(marker, i);
  if(i++ < nc.length) {
        setTimeout(function() {addmarker(i)}, 100);
    }

}
addmarker(0);
```

My code differs ever so slightly to the post in the link I mentioned, but I can't see why it shouldn't work regardless.

This is my working code (Drops all markers at once)...

```
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: 6,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(54.059170, -4.797820),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});


var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

var marker, i;

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    map: map,
    icon: EuroPCmarker,
  });


  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  })(marker, i));
}
```

JavaScript can be very unforgiving, It's hard to troubleshoot because if you make one error the map fails to display all together, I'm really at a loss here chaps and chappettes.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

**#firstpost**  :)

Comment: Can you post the code which sets `location`? I've started up a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Ytu9/) for this question.

Comment: Hi LaughDonor, apologies for the late reply. I've updated the JSFiddle you created with a slightly edited version of my code (removed company name, logos, sales data, etc.)

Comment: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Ytu9/2/)

Comment: You didn't split up your HTML from Javascript and CSS inside the Fiddle, and had a trailing comma inside the locations list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### This answer is based on markers dropping with a *'rainfall'* effect in succession.

Based on your updated [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22608540/google-marker-drop-animation-with-timeout/22643430#comment34558752_22643430), I've updated the last [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Ytu9/8/) to reflect your clarity of the question.

I basically swapped the `for` loop and `setTimeout` lines and used the `iterator` as a global variable.

```
iterator = 0; //Setup global iterator to go through markers
for(var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++)
    setTimeout( function() {
        //i can't be passed through because, by the time setTimeout executes, i == locations.length
        addMarker(locations);
    }, i * 500); //Execute addMarker every 500ms
```

Sorry for any confusion, this is all documented under the [Google Marker Animation Demo](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-animations-iteration).

Comment: Both answers will come in very handy, but this one in particular is exactly what I was looking for. Many thanks in abundance LaughDonor! :) appreciate your patience on this one.

Answer (score 1):

### This answer is based on OP's original question to drop all markers *simultaneously* after a set time

I've updated the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Ytu9/4/) with the fixes. Just like [Google Marker Animation Demo](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-animations-iteration), you just needed to add a set timeout for the part which instanciates the markers to the map.

I wrapped that key part inside an anonymous function, and called that 1 second after **DOM** and Google Maps API were ready using `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize );` at the end.

Comment: I still can't get it to play ball [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Ytu9/5/). I've separated the setTimeout and marker instance following the Google Marker Animation Demo's format. Adding the setTimeout is the bit I don't understand (as in, I don't know how to manipulate the code to work with the code I'm already using)

Comment: You've messed up with the braces in the JSFiddle. Their demo overcomplicated things inside the `setTimeout` function. `Location` and `i` do not have scope inside the `addMarker` function when you pulled that part of the code outside `initialize`. Wrapping a closure inside the `addListener` callback function is unnecessary. Google's Demo performs a different function, that is, to drop markers sequentially. You stated in OP you've wanted them dropped at the same time so I've changed this back. I've fixed up the references as well, as there were a bunch of issues with that code.

Comment: I think the main issue was the lack of comments in the code. My apologies for that, and I hope I've added a sufficient amount so that you can follow through what's happening this time. I've updated the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Ytu9/6/).

Comment: Apologies, I must have phrased my question poorly, I **am** able to drop all the markers at once, _however_, I would like the markers to drop **one-by-one** in quick succession (much like in this post: [Animation of google markers on map load with timeout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17890678/animation-of-google-markers-on-map-load-with-timeout). That's why I changed the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Ytu9/5/) here slightly to simulate **quote**: 'rain effect'. Sorry for the confusion.